# A case of usage of past perfect tense

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

I hit this in the "The Making of a Nation" series.

> The United States **had refused** to recognize the government in Moscow **after** the Bolsheviks **took** control in 1917.

This sentence seems odd to me as a non-native speaker.

I mean, what I know is that the past perfect describes actions that were completed before some point in the past. But it is not the case. I get confused. I think it has to be something like:

> The United States **refused** to recognize the government in Moscow **after** the Bolsheviks **had taken** control in 1917.

or

> The United States **refused** to recognize the government in Moscow **after** the Bolsheviks **took** control in 1917.

Here is the surrounding context of the quotation:

> One big question in American foreign policy in the 1930s concerned the Soviet union.
>
> The United States had refused to recognize the government in Moscow after the Bolsheviks took control in 1917. Yet Franklin Roosevelt saw the Soviet Union as a possible ally, if growing tensions in Europe and Asia burst into war.

[American History: Roosevelt's Foreign Policy in the 1930s](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/american-foreign-policy-in-the-1930s-120817734/116105.html)

Comment: Do earlier sentences refer to something that happened after 1917?

Comment: Here is the fairly full context.

"Some British leaders had so little faith in Roosevelt that they proposed seeking cooperation with Japan instead of the United States. New leaders in Japan, however, soon ended this possibility. They presented Britain with such strong military demands that the British government gave up any idea of cooperation with Japan.
One big question in American foreign policy in the 1930s concerned the Soviet union.
The United States had refused to recognize the government in Moscow after the Bolsheviks took control in 1917."

Comment: The general idea is: the past perfect precedes the simple past. So, you are right, they are wrong.

Comment: Something that happened in response to the Russian Revolution is in the past from the point of view of 'American foreign policy in the 1930s'. That is why the author refers to it in the perfect tense.

Answer (score 1):

The 'completed in the past' nature of past perfects doesn't require that the event must have happened before anything else in the sentence. It just requires that it happened before the implied 'now' of the sentence.

In your sentence, the event in 1917 is used as a time reference. The refusal happened after this time reference, but it (the refusal) was also 'completed' in the past. There is some flexibility in the use of tenses. Which tense the author picks depends on the nuance they want to convey.

- The dog *ate* after lunch. - Neutral proposition
- The dog *has eaten* after lunch. - Expresses the current state of the dog with respect to lunchtime.
- The dog *had eaten* after lunch. - Expresses the past state of the dog with respect to lunchtime.

In your example, the sentence conveys the idea that the refusal happened in the past, but the author wants to stress that it happened after a particular event.

Answer (score 1):

That one sentence, when viewed in isolation, does look a little odd, and either of your two suggestions would be valid replacements, and perhaps improvements.

However, when you read the preceding and the following sentences, you can see that there are other time references: "American foreign policy in the 1930s" and "[President] Franklin Roosevelt".

From the context of the 1930s, or Franklin Roosevelt's presidency (1933-1945), an action taken in 1917 would have been completed in their past, making the past perfect the appropriate tense.

I suspect that the choice of tense would have been easier to understand if the author had written that idea in two sentences, instead of three.  Something like this:

*One big question in American foreign policy in the 1930s concerned the Soviet union. Franklin Roosevelt believed that the Soviet Union could be a possible ally, even though The United States had refused to recognize the government in Moscow after the Bolsheviks took control in 1917*.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. The most "standard" way of writing this would be the way indicated by your first suggestion:

> The United States refused to recognize the government in Moscow after the Bolsheviks had taken control in 1917.

However, English speakers tend to be very loose with verb tenses, so your second suggestion (using only the simple past tense) occurs fairly often, and the original version appears occasionally, too.

Comment: "Some British leaders had so little faith in Roosevelt that they proposed seeking cooperation with Japan instead of the United States. New leaders in Japan, however, soon ended this possibility. They presented Britain with such strong military demands that the British government gave up any idea of cooperation with Japan.
One big question in American foreign policy in the 1930s concerned the Soviet union.
The United States had refused to recognize the government in Moscow after the Bolsheviks took control in 1917."

Comment: Above is the fairly full context. Based on that, do you think the original version is grammatically correct?

Comment: @PhuocHong As I said, English speakers tend to be loose with verb tenses, so different people will have different opinions of what is "correct". I would prefer ". . . had taken control in 1917."